# How do you declare a set-returning-function to only be allowed in the FROM clause?

Tags: postgresql, set-returning-functions

I was just reading [this answer by Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/124486). Informative as usual, it makes note that (multi-parameter) `unnest` is only allowed in the `FROM` clause. I had never tried it in the `SELECT` clause so I'm not that shocked, but I never saw function that could control for execution context: `FROM` vs `SELECT` set-returning-functions.

Docs for [`unnest(anyarray, anyarray [, ...])`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) (the version with multiple parameters)

> expand multiple arrays (possibly of different types) to a set of rows. **This is only allowed in the FROM clause;** see Section 7.2.1.4

How does one declare their set returning function to be FROM-clause only, or is this only permissible with `unnest`?

Comment: You might want to make clear that the restriction only applies to `unnest()` with multiple parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that's only possible with `unnest()` after all.

`unnest()` with multiple parameters is a special Postgres feature, that's internally rewritten into multiple `unnest()` calls that are combined more reasonably than parallel `unnest()` in the `SELECT` list would be, i.e. in a *sane* way if the number of elements does not match.

*The behavior was finally sanitized with Postgres 10:*

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in select clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

See:

```
EXPLAIN (VERBOSE) SELECT *
FROM   unnest('{a,b}'::text[], '{1,2}'::text[]);
```

```
Function Scan on unnest  (cost=0.01..1.00 rows=100 width=64)
  Output: unnest, unnest_1
  Function Call: unnest('{a,b}'::text[]), unnest('{1,2}'::text[])
```

It's a special use case for the `ROWS FROM` construct introduced with the same Postgres version 9.4. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS)

> **The special table function `UNNEST`** may be called with any number of
>   array parameters, and it returns a corresponding number of columns, as
>   if `UNNEST` ([Section 9.18](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)) had been called on each parameter separately
>   and combined using the `ROWS FROM` construct.

Bold emphasis mine.

If you try `unnest()` with multiple parameters in the `SELECT` list, you get:

> ERROR:  function unnest(text[], text[]) does not exist

In fact, there is no `unnest()` function with multiple parameters registered in the system:

```
SELECT proname, proargtypes, proargtypes[0]::regtype
FROM   pg_proc
WHERE  proname = 'unnest';
```

```
 proname | proargtypes | proargtypes
---------+-------------+-------------
 unnest  | 2277        | anyarray
 unnest  | 3614        | tsvector
```

That would be *confusing* if you were not aware of the first part of my answer.