# Looping with array of values in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, array

Can we use `RETURN QUERY` within this loop to display all values from `UserResponseList` instead of `RAISE NOTICE`?

```
FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(UserResponseList, 1)
LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %', QuestionList[i], UserResponseID_List[i], UserResponseList[i];
END LOOP;
```

Comment: The question seems clear enough to me. Neither of the 5 users who closed this question have activity in the [plpgsql] tag worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4):

> can we use return query within this loop ...?

You *can* use [`RETURN QUERY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_pivot_arrays()
  RETURNS TABLE(question text, response_id int, response text) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   QuestionList         text[] := '{Who?,When?,WHY?}';
   UserResponseID_List  int[]  := '{1,2,3}';
   UserResponseList     text[] := '{Here.,Now.,Because.}';
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(UserResponseList, 1)
   LOOP
      RETURN QUERY SELECT QuestionList[i], UserResponseID_List[i], UserResponseList[i];
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Or [`RETURN NEXT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING):

```
...
   FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(UserResponseList, 1)
   LOOP
      SELECT QuestionList[i], UserResponseID_List[i], UserResponseList[i]
      INTO   question,        response_id,            response;
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
...
```

But since Postgres 9.4, the simpler tool to unnest arrays in parallel is `unnest()`:

```
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT *
   FROM   unnest(QuestionList, UserResponseID_List, UserResponseList);
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7837c87473544d03ad6716b9a006275e)*

Related:

- [How do you declare a set-returning-function to only be allowed in the FROM clause?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160309/how-do-you-declare-a-set-returning-function-to-only-be-allowed-in-the-from-claus/160310#160310)

Comment: Great answer, Your answer is very helpful to me and also it is helpful for understand the array concepts within looping statements in pgsql.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like

```
select 
UserResponseList.UserResponseList , UserResponseID_List.value ,QuestionList.value

from
generate_series(1, array_upper(ARRAY[1,8,3,7,22,31], 1) ,1) UserResponseList 

left join
(   
    select generate_subscripts(a.arr,1) as subscript, a.arr[generate_subscripts(a.arr,1)] as value
    from (select ARRAY[25,8,3,7,29] as arr) a
)
UserResponseID_List on UserResponseList .UserResponseList  = UserResponseID_List .subscript 



left join
(   
    select generate_subscripts(a.arr,1) as subscript, a.arr[generate_subscripts(a.arr,1)] as value
    from (select ARRAY[1,3,16] as arr) a
)
QuestionList on UserResponseList .UserResponseList  = QuestionList .subscript
```

Comment: No, My question is can we use return query instead of raise notice within the looping statements to getting an output of all data from the particular array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can what you want is [parallel array `unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html).

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (), *
FROM table
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest( QuestionList, UserResponseID_List, UserResponseList );
```

I'm not sure what this has to do with `RAISE NOTICE`, but I imagine you can figure it out from there.

Comment: No, My question is can we use return query instead of raise notice within the looping statements to getting an output of all data from the particular array.